# What is the difference between STAsText() and ToString() in sql while converting geography to wkt

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, spatial-data

```
DECLARE @geographyData geography; 
//Convert wkt to geography 

SET @geographyData = geography::Parse('LINESTRING(-132.360 50.657, -120.340 47.659)');


//Convert back to wkt from geography

(1) @geographyData.ToString();

(2) @geographyData.STAsText();
```

(1) and (2) giving me same result that is LINESTRING (-132.36 50.657, -120.340 47.659). What is the difference between ToString() and STAsText()?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, `ToString()` returns the value [representation of a geography instance augmented with any Z (elevation) and M (measure) values carried by the instance.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/tostring-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017)

However, the `STAsTEXT()` function [text will not contain any Z (elevation) or M (measure) values carried by the instance.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stastext-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017)

There does seem to be some overlap in these SQL Geography functions.

Answer (score 5):

STAsText (geography Data Type)
this will return  text will **not** contain any Z (elevation) or M (measure) values carried by the instance

but

ToString (geography Data Type)
this will return  text will contain any Z (elevation) or M (measure) values carried by the instance

Example:

DECLARE @g geometry;
SET @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(1 2 3 4)', 0);

SELECT @g.ToString();  -- Result    **POINT (1 2 3 4)**

SELECT @g.STAsText()   -- Result    **POINT (1 2)**